# Serverless offline not taking environment variables

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless, aws-secrets-manager

I am new to serverless and would like your help to figure out what I am doing wrong.
In my local development after using `sls offline --config cusom.yml` i am unable to retrieve secrets. After a bit of debugging, found out that the credentials is null.

However, when i invoke it separately using pure js aws-sdk (not with serverless) I am able to retrieve the secrets and the credentials is prepopulated. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on why this is not working with `sls offline`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the following files locally?

```
~/.aws/credentials
~/.aws/config
```

These files serves as the credentials if you don't write them in your code. Most libraries and aws cli relies on them for access

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials 
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = your_aws_secret_access_key
aws_access_key_id = your_aws_access_key_id

$ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = us-east-1  # or your preferred region
```